# How to re-render component in react native expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a video component and enterFullscreen function with changing screen orientation logic, I want to re-render the video component after changing screen orientation because it has a width property in style. I tried to use use-force-update and changing state but it doesn't help.

```js
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')
async function enterFullscreen() {
    if (!isFullscreen) {
        await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE)
        // re-render here
    }
    else {
        await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP)
        // re-render here
    }
}
```

```js
video: {
  width: width,
  height: height,
  zIndex: 1
},
```

```js
import { Video, ResizeMode } from 'expo-av';

<Video
    ref={video}
    style={styles.video}
    source={source}
    resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
    onReadyForDisplay={getDurationMillis}
    onPlaybackStatusUpdate={getPositionMillis}
    onLoad={() => {setIsLoading(false)}}
/>
```

Default
[image: Default]

How it is(wrong)
[image: How it is(wrong)]

How it should be
[image: How i should be]

If I press ctrl+s after entering Fullscreen mode, video has right width, if I don't it's like on 2nd screenshot
How can I re-render my component?

Comment: what about just a simple `useState()` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely that you're calculating `width` outside of the body of the component. React will only update values inside React components. I'm guessing that you're getting the screen dimensions like this:

```js
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  video: {
    width: width,
    height: height,
    zIndex: 1
  },
});

const VideoComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Video
      style={styles.video}
      // ...
```

When you need to react to changes in screen dimensions, React Native provides the [useWindowDimensions hook](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions).  To use it, you'll need to make some changes in your code.

1. Move the dimensions-getting inside the component (because it's a hook, but also because it allows you to react to changes).
2. Define the width and height styles dynamically, inside your component's render.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  video: {
    zIndex: 1
  },
});

const VideoComponent = () => {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();

  return (
    <Video
      style={[styles.video, { width, height }]}
      // ...
```

You also might get away with doing none of this and replacing the width and height in your styles with `{ flex: 1 }`, but I haven't tested that.